# How do I serialize ScriptableObjects?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using a save system I don't fully understand but works well. It saves serializable code, but I started using ScriptableObjects as a way to save inventory and it broke and I don't know how to fix it now.

This is the code I'm using:

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Attack")]
 public class PlayerAttckCard : ScriptableObject
{
    public string AtackName,bookName;
    public bool multiTarget;
    public float Bacepower;
    public GameObject miniGame;
}
```

I tried using `[System.Serializable]`
but I got this  error:

> SerializationException: Type UnityEngine.ScriptableObject in assembly
>   UnityEngine.CoreModule, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null is not marked as serializable.

Do I need to change how I'm saving my game or is there a way to fix this?

Comment: For storing simple data persistently you could look at [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html). For more complex data I'ld recommend to rather use something like [JSON](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual//JSONSerialization.html) or [XML](https://unity3d.college/2017/07/14/using-unity3d-xml-files-game-data-quiz-game-example/)

Comment: But why you need to do this. ScriptableObject is already a sort of unity serialization format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Serializing to JSON? You can do this with JsonUtility.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html

```
public class TestObject : ScriptableObject
{
    public string foo, bar;
}

var obj = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<TestObject>();
obj.foo = "hello";
obj.bar = "world";
var json = JsonUtility.ToJson(obj);
Debug.Log(json); // {"foo":"hello","bar":"world"}

obj.foo = "something";
obj.bar = "else";
JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(json, obj);
Debug.Log(obj.foo + ", " + obj.bar); // hello, world
```

Answer (score 1):

As much as I know, you can't, it's possible doing a custom inspector, editor, gui, but it's quite tricky, I don't know how to do it even. but maybe, you can to do this.

```
[System.serializable]
public class PlayerAttackCard
{
   public string AtackName,bookName;
   public bool multiTarget;
   public float Bacepower;
   public GameObject miniGame;
}
```

And the scriptable object.

```
public class PlayerAttackCardData : ScriptableObject
{
    public PlayerAttackCard playerAttackCard = new PlayerAttackCard();
}
```

Comment: A custom editor won't help much for getting the data saved persistently in a build...

Comment: You can´t because `SerializableObjects` are meant to be treated as files with `Asset Packages`, that means you can't `Serialize` an `ScribtableObject`, if you want to store and save on a cloud or server you should export and import it using `Asset packages`.

To save serializable things just use a normal class.

I reccommend using the solution Lobsang White provided.

You save on a `Serializable` class and load on `ScriptableObjects`.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to use it, you can put them together or seperate, im getting no error

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "item.asset",menuName = "inventory/item")][ System.Serializable]
public class Item:ScriptableObject
```

or

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "item.asset",menuName = "inventory/item"), System.Serializable]
public class Item:ScriptableObject
```